# To-ground buttons only work when Arduino is powered via USB

Tags: arduino, ground, button

The following PCB does not respond to buttons if powered via 5 V / GND connections, but does work when powered via mini USB. Any ideas? Many thanks.

[image: pcb front]

[image: pcb back]

[image: schematics]

Main thread: https://github.com/kachurovskiy/nanoels/discussions/17

Comment: Have you checked continuity from the button ground to the Arduino ground, using a multimeter? Also, check the voltage on the Arduino inputs using multimeter. Both when button is pressed and when not.

Comment: Make sure that all grounds are connected.  Also, based on the source code, buttons use internal MCU pull-up, which is very weak. Try adding ~4.7K ohms external pull-up resistors to a buttons.

Comment: Could you show the code?

Answer (score 2):

It is clear from the PCB photos that the common pins of most buttons (D6, D6, etc) are not connected to the copper pour representing the GND net. Some do appear to be connected (LEFT button) and may work properly. See highlights in yellow for separate GND net, then blue highlights proper connection to GND.

[image]

This is likely the cause of the buttons connected to a net that doesn't match to real GND net, even though it appears to be the same name on the schematic. A stray space in the net name could cause this. To fix, just solder a wire from that false GND net to the real one. Or better yet, just scrap away some of the solder mask on the real GND (near the button pin) and apply some solder.

See example here:

[image]